# SqlFunctions.StringConvert unnecessary padding added

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

In my ViewModel i am returning the following for a dropdown list:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses
    {
        get
        {
            using (var context = new AssetManager.Models.AssetManagerEntities())
            {
                var query = from status in context.AssetStatuses
                            where status.Reserved != true
                            select new SelectListItem()
                                       {
                                           Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)status.Id),
                                           Text = status.Name,
                                           Selected = false
                                       };

                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my View it goes a little like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Statuses)
```

This all works ok, except that SqlFunctions.StringConvert, by default makes the string a length of 10, so i end up with this in the html:

```
<option value="         7">Free to loan</option>
```

Take note of the spacing in the value field.  This is a problem, because my ViewModel requires this field to be an int.

I could simply specify the length parameter but this is not dynamic.

Has anyone seen this problem, or have a resolution to it?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)status.Id).Trim() will do it.

Comment: I think tim's answer is better than mine. You should accept his answer so I can delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

[Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11688477/120955) below is a better solution than this one, but I am unable to delete the accepted answer, and the OP has not responded to my requests to accept his answer.

#### Original Answer

The easiest way to do this would probably be to offload the conversion effort onto your server, rather than the data context. If you were separating your data tier from your presentation tier, this would happen automatically. But for simplicity's sake, I'll just stick with your current architecture:

```
            var query = from status in context.AssetStatuses
                        where !status.Reserved
                        select new 
                                   {
                                       status.Id,
                                       status.Name
                                   };
            return query.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(status => new SelectListItem
                                   {
                                       Value = status.Id.ToString(),
                                       Text = status.Name,
                                       Selected = false
                                   })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Because i end up with:


`System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @Nick Vierros: My bad: I was testing against LINQ to SQL. I'll update my answer momentarily, and add the `entity-framework` tag to your post.

Comment: Note that this works because the .AsEnumerable() forces the query to execute, so the .ToString() runs in LINQ to Objects, not LINQ to Entities.  If you were expecting to defer execution, you'll need another solution.

Comment: @ScottStafford: You're correct that the `.AsEnumerable()` causes `.ToString()` to run in LINQ to Objects. However, this has little to do with deferred execution. You're not going to get deferred execution out of this method at any rate, because you're disposing the context before the method ends. If you had a different life-cycle for the context, then you could simply omit the `.ToList()` and get deferred execution.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Certainly true. I only comment to explain to readers WHY your solution works, which you clearly know but EF newbies may not realize.

Answer (score 35):

Change it to:

```
Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)status.Id).Trim(),
```

Comment: The trim sorted me out... must have been badly formatted data under the hood. But blimey did I spend a while figuring this out! Thanks.

Comment: Is there any significant difference between using (double) and using (decimal)?

Comment: @ScottStafford: Because the value has no decimal part to it, using `decimal` would not give you any extra precision. There may be a miniscule performance benefit to using `double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses
{
    get
    {
        using (var context = new AssetManager.Models.AssetManagerEntities())
        {
            return  (from status in context.AssetStatuses.ToList()
                        where status.Reserved != true
                        select new SelectListItem()
                                   {
                                       Value = status.Id.ToString(),
                                       Text = status.Name,
                                       Selected = false
                                   });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option that works with LINQ to Entities is to do a concatenation with an implicit type conversion such as  `Value = "" & status.Id`.  However, this will cause issues that have to be worked around if you want to use multiple concatenation using this method.